# Hide and Show View after animation is finished in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

How to hide and show an Image/View after an animation is done in SwiftUI.

```
Image(systemName: "arrow.2.circlepath.circle.fill")
    .rotationEffect(.degrees(spin ? 360 : 0))
    .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.8).repeatCount(5))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use one variable to control the rotation and a second one to control the alpha:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var degrees: Double = 0
  @State var alpha: Double = 1
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "arrow.2.circlepath.circle.fill")
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(degrees))
        .onAppear(perform: {
          withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 0.8).repeatCount(5)) {
            self.degrees = 360
          }
          DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4) {
            self.alpha = 0
          }
        })
        .opacity(alpha)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think solution will work but but problem is is this how Apple wants us to do it? With UIKit its isHidden flag true or false. If I need to add DispatchQueue for every time I need to hide and show a view this will get very complicated.

Comment: The “DispatchQueue....” part helped me solve hiding a Popover after a few seconds. Thanks.